# "One lumen ... it is ... one candela per steradian." Meaning of "per" as "times"; Is phrase correct definition?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm posting question here, not physics cause I doubt the phrase if wrong, maybe my understanding of English is not correct here, namely can "per" same as "times" in some contexts (division vs multiplication)?
Here [lux_meters_light_meters](https://www.globalspec.com/learnmore/optics_optical_components/optoelectronics/lux_meters_light_meters)

> One lumen is the true visible light irradiance of a source—it is equivalent to one candela per three-dimensional angle measured, or one candela per steradian.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumen)

> The lumen is related to the candela as

> 1 lm = 1 cd ⋅ sr.

So in the first quoted article they used "per" in place of "times". Could it be correct/acceptable usage of "per"? To rephrase in more common terms, millage of car is miles per gallon. Can one say than "distance is millage per gallon"?

Comment: I think that this question would be best answered on the physics site.  When you calculate miles per gallon you do a **division**. If you make up a new unit to  replace miles per gallon, you describe the new unit using a **multiplication** of miles and gallons. I'll leave it to the physicists to explain why. **per** means **divided by**, not **times**.

Comment: "Per" expresses a **rate**, which is mathematically expressed with division. I am not sure the sentence you cite is correct; technically perhaps it should be "one candela-steradian" (where the hyphenation of units indicates multiplication rather than division; compare "kilowatt-hour").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look further down the page at the Wikipedia article,
[Wikipedia *lumen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumen_(unit))
there is a table.
The second and third entries show
2 luminous flux (**lumen = candela-steradian**)
3 luminous intensity (**candela = lumen per steradian**)

So, as the comments correctly point out, **per means division**. The juxtaposition of two units, or placing a dot between them, means multiplication. The first article you cite is just wrong.

As to mileage (note spelling), it is expressed as miles per gallon, or miles/gallon.
If you want to express distance in terms of the other two, it would be
distance (miles) = mileage (miles per gallon) x gallons.

Comment: That is what I thought, just was not sure as I am not a native English speaker. Thank you!